# Pasar JSON desde JS(JQuery) a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ya he intentado y buscado pero sigue sin funcionar.

Este es mi código en JS:

```
var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 3);

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById("JsonData").innerHTML = JSONstr;
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", "lista.php", true)
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
  xhttp.send()
```

El código php no tengo seguro como recibirlo ya que en diferentes sitios el código era diferente y ninguno funciono como tal.

Comment: Hola en lista.php escribe `var_dump($_REQUEST);` y revisas qué llega. Luego, si no es suficiente para resolver, incluye lo que muestre en la pregunta.

Comment: El resultado es: array (size=2)
  'idCategoria' => string '10' (length=2)
  'txtIDGrupo' => string '10' (length=2)

Ni siquiera es el JSON esperado.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no ha sido agregado al hacer el request. Revisa los parámetros de send(). En el ejemplo en la documentación MDN aparece send(cadena) cuando usan método post [ver: XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) ya copio el ejemplo:

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/server', true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
}
xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");  **<- esta linea llevaría tu JSON**
// xhr.send(new Int8Array()); 
// xhr.send(document);

Answer (score 0):

Listo, si recivo la variable, pero solo la puedo ver en Inspeccionar > Network > XHR pero no en el HTML.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código de PHP para recibir la variable es:

```
<?php 

$requestPayload = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $requestPayload;
```